# Как в WP перехватить событие завершения работы плагина

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я хочу запускать свой плагин после выполнения другого плагина в WP. Такое возможно? Если да, то каким хуком это можно сделать?

Имеется ввиду следующая ситуация: плагин "WooCommerce and 1C:Enterprise/1С:Предприятие Data Exchange" работает при экспорте фида из 1С. Сразу после его работы мне необходимо изменить некоторые атрибуты товаров. Плагин изменения атрибутов у меня написан, но сейчас он выполняется по расписанию wp-cron, а мне нужно чтобы мой плагин выполнялся сразу же после завершения работы плагина "WooCommerce and 1C:Enterprise/1С:Предприятие Data Exchange".

Comment: Это нерешаемо в общем случае. Плагины сами работают по хукам, и могут использовать любые, вплоть до shutdown. Вам надо разобраться, после какой именно функциональности другого плагина вы хотите выполнить действие в своём.

Answer (score 2):

Комментируя вопрос, я как в воду глядел по поводу хука `shutdown`.

Плагин `WooCommerce and 1C:Enterprise/1С:Предприятие Data Exchange` (`WC1C`) начинает свою работу на хуке `template_redirect` с приоритетом `-10`, а заканчивает, закрывая транзакцию в базе, на php-хуке `shutdown`. php-хуки shutdown выполняются в том порядке, как они были зарегистрированы.

В вашем плагине надо зарегистрировать свой php-хук shutdown после WC1C и уже в нём выполнить необходимые действия.

```
function my_shutdown_function() {
    global $wc1c_is_transaction;

    // Если WC1C отработал, то wc1c_is_transaction  должна быть false.
    if ( ! isset( $wc1c_is_transaction ) || false !== wc1c_is_transaction) {
        return;
    }

    // Здесь ваши действия по изменению атрибутов товара.
}

function my_template_redirect() {
    register_shutdown_function( 'my_shutdown_function' );
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Переменная $wc1c_is_transaction is NULL. Ни разу после работы плагина переменная не возвращала ни false ни true, всегда null

Comment: @QueidLow не там смотрели. В этом куске кода, на хуке, она должна быть определена.

Comment: смотрел в условии ( ! isset( $wc1c_is_transaction ) || false !== wc1c_is_transaction). Условие всегда return. Такое ощущения что глобальные переменные wc обнуляются после того как плагин к которому мы цепляемся завершает работу. Пробовал получить еще одну переменную $wc_deferred_product_sync, она тоже null.

Comment: На хуке init смог поймать значение глобальной переменной **$wc1c_is_transaction** true

Answer (score 0):

Есть хук/экшн **plugin_loaded**, он срабатывает после загрузки указанного в параметре плагина.

В параметр передаётся путь к главному файлу плагина. Например **plugin-slug/plugin-slug.php**

Comment: Ответ не о том. Хук plugin_loaded срабатывает сразу после загрузки плагина. Ни одного хука в плагине к этому моменту не выполнено. А ТС спрашивает, как отследить завершение работы *всего* плагина.

Comment: В вопросе написано "после выполнения плагина". На это хуке плагин загрузился и его линейный код выполнился: создание страниц, инициализация классов, функций, свои хуков. Думаю именно это имел ввиду ТС.

Comment: @QueidLow вам надо не ответ писать, а отредактировать вопрос вот с этой информацией

Comment: @Temyk а я думал, что автор имеет ввиду весь код плагина, со всеми хуками. И угадал.

Comment: Вот почему нужно задавать вопрос конкретнее. @QueidLow тогда вам нужен хук этого плагина